# UNITY. Очень долго загружается сцена при открытии проекта и также долго обновляются различные изменения в проекте

Tags: c#, unity3d

При любом изменении в Unity (при запуске игры, обновлении скрипта C#, воспроизведении чего-либо), появляется прямоугольное окно с надписью "Hold on" (еще может дописаться рядом "busy for"). Хотя смотрел у других разработчиков, и у них прям моментально все обновляется, хотя мой компьютер точно нельзя назвать слабым (скрин окна ниже)

[image: Обновление чего-либо в Unity]

Еще большее время занимает открытие самого проекта из Unity Hub. Там надпись "busy for" может доходить до 5-6 минут.

[image: Загрузка сцены Unity]

Не понимаю, почему так. Проекты все лежат на SSD, никакие инструкции не помогают. Надеюсь на последний шанс спасения - ответ специалистов здесь. Заранее спасибо

Характеристики ПК
[image]

SSD:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Производитель: A-Data

Comment: прикрепи характеристики компьютера и точную модель и производителя ссд.

Comment: добавил данные ниже

Comment: Ну как "нельзя назвать слабым". i3 с двумя физическими ядрами и 8Гб ОЗУ? Для серьёзных проектов маловато. Откройте "Диспетчер задач", а в нём вкладку "Производительность". И сделайте с неё скриншот в тот момент, когда у вас это вот "busy for" происходит. Многое станет яснее. Скорее всего процессор захлёбывается, но, возможно, и памяти не хватает, начинает своповать. Ещё посмотрите, сколько свободного места на SSD. Если меньше 50%, то у дешёвых дисков начинается сильное падение производительности при такой заполненности. А если ещё и своп пишется на этот же диск...

Comment: @CrazyElf для пустого проэкта с кубом - этого процессора точно хватать должно)) А вот самая дешевая китайская ссдха наверняка тормозная часть. Вероятнее всего не будет иметь даже области кеша для нормализации скорости. А это в свою очередь тот же своп делает медленным аж до 50-70 мегабайт скорости что весьма грустно. Но да, профайлер в операционке использовать это хорошая идея.

Comment: @Andrew Всё может быть, но мне казалось современные дешёвые ссд всё же не настолько плохи. Пусть правда тесты погоняет. Может у него кроме юнити ещё браузер открыт, телега и всякое прочее, а в результате тупо память кончается. Так то если один юнити, то 8Гб и правда должно наверное хватать, но тогда непонятно. Не думаю, что там страшные гигабайты нужно грузить, основной смысл ссд всё же в том, что он мелкие файлы быстро отдаёт, а это не должно вроде настолько плохо быть у дешёвых ссд.

Comment: @CrazyElf У ссд все очень плохо. Даже у средней ценовой категории. Средняя  и средне-дорогая ценовая категория спасает кешом быстрой памяти а из кеша пишет на очень медленную ссд память. Кеш закончился - начались тормоза. А у дешевой ценовой категории кеша может не быть вообще.

Comment: Дело не в железе. Долгая загрузка - это норма для Unity.

Answer (score 0):

У тебя стоит весьма стремная ссд-ха. 99% что вся проблема именно в ней.

Вероятнее всего у нее реальная скорость будет около 50-70 мегабайт, что ниже чем у неплохого винта раза в 2-3. И ниже чем у чесной нормальной ссд-хи в 10 раз.

Для того что бы проверить что дело именно что в ней можешь проверить это следующими способами:

- Переписать файл с иного винчестера при помощи тотал коммандера - он весьма точно показывает скорость копирования. Файл должен быть большим - хотя бы гигабайт на 10-15-20. С флешки не подходит. Только иной винчестер.
- Проверить скорость при помощи бесплатной консольной тулзовины  [github.com/Alois-xx/FileStress](https://github.com/Alois-xx/FileStress) На файле в 2-3 гигабайта. Больше -- можешь. Меньше - не советую.
- Проверить скорость при помощи Victoria
- Проверить скорость при помощи PC-3000 Disk Analyzer

Собственно, тебя интересует начало "графика" в первую очередь.

## Ни в коем случае НЕ проверять на CrystalDiskMark!!!! Это бессмысленно.

Если проблема окажется в ССД - советую купить Samsung Evo любого вида. Даже б.у. покатит. Формфактор выбирай по своему железу - покатит и 2,5" если на матери нету m2. Если есть - лучше m2. Эта "переплата" гарантирует нормальное качество.

---

так же хорошая идея заглянуть в профайлер операционной системы, как написал CrazyElf. ("Диспетчер задач" -> "Производительность" во время открытия юнити )